# word "newcomers"

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am writing an answer and I need some help chosing the correct word.

Is "newcomers" the correct word? I want to express that "for those who just read that question", the question might make people confused in some ways.

Comment: Yes **newcomers** is correct.

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb thank you for confirming for me ;P